# General proof of formulas of geometric optics?

Tags: optics, conventions, geometric-optics, lenses

In most lf textbooks formulas of geometric optics like lens maker formula and base formula for that are proven (or rather verified from my point of view) by taking specific case (ray diagram) and formulate equation and stated that works for all cases because we use sign convention. Why?

Here is link for that what i mean by sign convention
www.tutorvista.com/content/science/science-ii/reflection-

image.wistatutor.com/content/refraction-light/lens-sign-c

Comment: "Sign convention?" Can you be a bit more descriptive in your question? I would probably want to show a couple of constructions for positive and negative focal lengths, rather than wave my hands. Do you have an example of such a "proof"?

Comment: Does *because it explains what we actually observe* count as a reason why?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP wants to know how one can use snell's law and some geometry to demonstrate that provided one uses certain sign conventions, one can predict e.g. image distances using the lens equation.  I'm confident that someone can recommend a reference on geometric optics that does this sort of thing in detail.

Comment: @joshphysics you mean like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics and references therein?  :-).  Or, of course,  Smith, "Modern OPtical Engineering"

Comment: @joshphysics
yah that,
 Optics Geometrical optics, or ray optics, describes light propagation in terms of rays

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I knew it!

Comment: Question perfectly unclear, link perfectly not working ! What is a "lense-maker-formula" ? What is the "sign-convention" you mention ? As far as I remember, the geometrical optics is just about vector addition and subtraction. I guess there is no sign convention. If you want to see how to recover geometrical optics from electromagnetism, open volume 2 of Landau and Lifshitz lectures on theoretical physics. I'm not sure it will help nevertheless :-/